# Can I change img src in html?

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview

It's like

```
<img src="somesrc" file="filepath" />
```

The src is not the correct url, how can I load the img using the url in file attribute for all images?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery
/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <img src="wrongsrc" file="http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/uc_server/data/avatar/000/52/56/39_avatar_middle.jpg"></img>

    <script >   
$("img").each(function(){
var filepath = $(this).prop("file");
if (filepath) this.src=filepath; 
}); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I change my code to this, but it does not work.

Comment: Read the HTML file as string, replace the url with your url, and use the latest string to show HTML using loadHTMLString function of UIWebView.

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but it is a littler slower.

Comment: You can choose to write the new html as file, if it is not changing you can later read from local with your images. It will be faster from next run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery to edit all of your images:

```js
$(function() {    
  $("img").each(function(){
    var filepath = $(this).attr("file");
    if (filepath) this.src=filepath; 
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="wrongsrc" file="http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/uc_server/data/avatar/000/52/56/39_avatar_middle.jpg"></img>
  <img src="wrongsrc" file="http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/uc_server/data/avatar/000/52/56/39_avatar_middle.jpg"></img>
  <img src="wrongsrc" file="http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/uc_server/data/avatar/000/52/56/39_avatar_middle.jpg"></img>
  <img src="wrongsrc" file="http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/uc_server/data/avatar/000/52/56/39_avatar_middle.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: I want to change all the img,not only the image have id my_image?how can i do that ,thank you

Comment: You're right, just changed my code up there to get the file attr

Comment: When did that code call? I have a img in body:<img src="wrongsrc" file="http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/uc_server/data/avatar/000/52/56/39_avatar_middle.jpg"></img> and those script in header,but it does not work? why?

Comment: Either wrap the script in a $( document ).ready(function() {...} or put the script at the bottom of the html. Running the script before the html loads can lead to unpredictable results

Comment: I fixed it for you. Several errors there - missing brackets, this is $(this) if you want the attributes and prop is the better way.

Comment: I edit the problem, it does not work ,could you see it again ?

Comment: Using .attr fixed it - `file` was not a property of image but a self invented attribute - a better solution is `data-file('....')` then `$(this).data("file")` will get the attribute

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to each image

For HTML

```
<img SRC="somesource" id="1" />
<img SRC="somesource" id="2" />
<img SRC="somesource" id="3" />
```

For JavaScript

```
(document).ready(function (){
$("img").each(function() {
var id = $(this).attr('id')
$(this).attr('src', ''+id+'_image.png');
});
});
```

Rename your images like 1_image.PNG, 2_image.PNG and so on

It sounds confusing but may work, inform if it works, on a mobile device so can't test it myself.

Comment: I want change all the img src attribute ,not only one img

Comment: Add this code in the for loop add change ImgSelector to this

Comment: Could you tell me why the below html does not show what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Please use another version of jQuery and it will work fine.

```js
jQuery("img").each(function(){
  var filepath = jQuery(this).attr("file");
  if (filepath) this.src=filepath; 
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<img src="wrongsrc" file="http://www.hi-pda.com/forum/uc_server/data/avatar/000/52/56/39_avatar_middle.jpg">
```

Comment: I seems that in ios UIWebView does not support jQuery, how can i do that?

Comment: You just need to change "<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery
/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>" in your given code, the url only

Comment: You can replace `jQuery("img").each(function(){
var filepath = jQuery(this).attr("file");
if (filepath) this.src=filepath; 
});  `   with  `$("img").each(function(){
var filepath = $(this).attr("file");
if (filepath) this.src=filepath; 
}); `

Comment: Thank you.It works fine in my chrom.But in ios UIWebView, it does not work?

Comment: what is the issue with "ios UIWebView"?

Comment: I seems the problem is the script in head.But I do not know how to fix it

Comment: please check in HiPDA/HiPDA V2/HiPDA V2/Views/LZHPostList.html

Comment: change "<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>" with "<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>"

Comment: I solved it using javascript, I do not know why the jQuery do not work on ios. the javascript code is here: var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

            for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
                imgs[i].src=imgs[i].getAttribute("file");
            }

Comment: Ah, apologies. I see he added my code and you took his - I am on my phone and did not look at his modified question

Comment: Actually the issue was not the jQuery version as much as .prop does not work on user created attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is right, it goes will when I run it in chrome in a PC.But when I put that code in ios, it seems there is a little problem about using jQuery in ios.Maybe I did not using jQuery in the right way.I solved my problem using the method below:

```
    <script  type="text/javascript">
        var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            if(imgs[i].getAttribute("file")!=null&&imgs[i].getAttribute("file")!=undefined){
                imgs[i].src=imgs[i].getAttribute("file");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: The last issue was jQuery cannot use prop on user created attributes.